# Wordpress pages not appearing in parent page list

Tags: wordpress

We have a custom Wordpress website that was built for us by consultants.  We're in the process of trying to change the page structure / heirarchy around a little which involves changing page names and reassigning some pages to different parents. (Edit page --> Page Attributes --> Parent Page)  The strange thing we're seeing is that the pages we udpate don't seem to be a choice in the parent page lists of the other pages.

What we've tried:

- Going to settings --> Permalinks and hitting "save" (even without making any changes to that screen)
- Clearing the Wordpress Cache
- Clearing the CDN Cache
- Restarting the server that Wordpress is on

A combination of the above as well as saving / resaving the pages in question.  Nothing seems to work.

We could turn off all the plugins and see if that fixes it and then turn them all on one at a time, but I was hoping to avoid that.  (As I understand it, there are some plugins that will cause some issues if turned off.)  We could also try to see if the original consultants are able to assist, be we're trying to avoid that option as well.

We have a Dev & a staging site, but of course, we're not seeing the issue on either of those sites.

Yes, I've already searched Google and the wordpress forums but was unable to find anything useful.

We are using Wordpress Core 6.1.1 and keep the plugins updated on a weekly basis.  We do have the Gutenberg editor active.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for disabling plugins and reenabling them download this plugin
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/

Its really great and if you run into any fatal errors the plugin can restore itself back to its prior state to before the error so that may help with eliminating plugins as a cause.

What I would also do is check to ensure you don't have a hierarchy override as its possible they could of hard coded the parent pages in when doing this for you so you may not be able to change these if that is the case without changing some code although I am doubtful they have done that.

If you cant find the issue it could be in direct cololation with your theme possible if that is the case you could reach out to the dev teams for advice or check the community forms to see if anyone else is having these issues.

From the limited information you have provided I would guess this is a theme issue.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  Any idea if it's possible that this issue could be due to multiple pages with the same name (but different slugs)?

Comment: the slugs are the main thing in this conversation so as long as the slugs are unique your title can be the same.  for example you could have 2 pages called home but as long as the slug on one is called home and the other is home-one there shouldn't be an issue. @WarpCoreBreach

Comment: We still aren't able to figure this out.  Looks like we'll have to turn off all the plugins and troubleshoot it that way...  that'll be fun!  :-)